# Installing modules inside python .py file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am deploying a custom pytorch model on AWS sagemaker, Following [this](https://github.com/abiodunjames/MachineLearning/blob/master/DeployYourModelToSageMaker/inference.py) tutorial.
In my case I have few dependencies to install some modules.

I need pycocotools in my inference.py script. I can easily install pycocotool inside a separate notebook using this bash command,

`%%bash`

`pip -g install pycocotools`

But when I create my endpoint for deployment, I get this error that pycocotools in not defined.
I need pycocotools inside my inference.py script. How I can install this inside a .py file

Comment: How about running a shell script in the beginning of the code inside inference.py where it runs `pip install`?

Comment: Look for example [here](https://github.com/Altabeh/tesseract-ocr-wrapper/blob/a6487f2215bac2140d6a90a74992f7d6cae4959e/_sys.py#L15)

Comment: Thanks, let me give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of inference.py add these lines:

```
from subprocess import check_call, run, CalledProcessError
import sys
import os

# Since it is likely that you're going to run inference.py multiple times, this avoids reinstalling the same package:
if not os.environ.get("INSTALL_SUCCESS"):
    
    try:
        check_call(
        [ sys.executable, "pip", "install", "pycocotools",]
        )
    except CalledProcessError:
        run(
        ["pip", "install", "pycocotools",]
        )
    os.environ["INSTALL_SUCCESS"] = "True"
```

Comment: I get this error, "OriginalMessage": "Command '['/opt/conda/bin/python3.6', 'pip', 'install', 'pycocotools']' returned non-zero exit status. Please note, it may work in simple scnerio, but I am using it in deploying sagemaker endpoint and testing it on Postman app

Comment: This worked for me anyhow. Thanks!
`import subprocess`

`list_files = subprocess.run(["pip", "install", "pycocotools"])`